# Is it true that year $y$ is a leap year in the Gregorian calendar if and only if $y \in (4\mathbb{Z}) \Delta (100\mathbb{Z}) \Delta (400\mathbb{Z}$)?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

A leap year in the Gregorian calendar is any year that is divisible by 4, excluding the ones that are divisible by 100, but including the ones that are divisible by 400.

So, now, my question is: Is it true that year $y$ is a leap year in the Gregorian calendar (proleptic if $y \le 1582)$ if and only if $y \in (4\mathbb{Z}) \Delta (100\mathbb{Z}) \Delta (400\mathbb{Z}$), where $\Delta$ denotes the symmetric difference of sets?

Remember that the intersection of three sets is contained in their symmetric difference. Also, BC years are to be converted to the corresponding non-positive years using [astronomical year numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_year_numbering).

Of course, $m$ is divisible by $n$ if and only if $m \in n\mathbb{Z}$, so this statement may in particular be applied for $n \in \{4,100,400\}$. While this statement is about individual factors, considering symmetric differences makes things more complicated.

Comment: You can answer this by considering a small example.  $A=\{4,100,400\}, B=\{100,400\}, C=\{400\}$  What is   $A\Delta B\Delta C$?

Comment: I don't think symetric differences are associative.  So the statement $A\triangle B \triangle C$ is ambiguous.  Does it mean $(A\triangle B)\triangle C$ or $A\triangle (B\triangle C)$ or $(A\triangle C)\triangle B$.  Those are *all* completely different sets.  What you described is $4\mathbb Z\triangle (100\mathbb Z \triangle 400\mathbb Z)$.  Which is very different from $(4 \mathbb Z \triangle 100\mathbb Z)\triangle 400\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @fleablood - Symmetric difference $\triangle$ is associative. See [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Symmetric_Difference_is_Associative) for a proof.

Comment: Actually as written, it is not true, since in the Gregorian calendar there is no year $0$, and no negative years (and because of the former, it also doesn't make sense to associate BC dates with negative year numbers).

Comment: @celtschk - Right, thank you for your comment. I included a remark in my answer to take it into account.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, an year $y \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ is leap  if and only if $y \in (4\mathbb{Z}) \,\triangle\, (100\mathbb{Z}) \,\triangle\, (400\mathbb{Z})$. Let us see why.

Note that $(4\mathbb{Z}) \,\triangle\, (100\mathbb{Z}) \,\triangle\, (400\mathbb{Z}) = 4\mathbb{Z} \smallsetminus (100\mathbb{Z} \smallsetminus 400\mathbb{Z})$, since $ 400\mathbb{Z} \subseteq 100\mathbb{Z} \subseteq 4\mathbb{Z}$ (see ${}^*$ below).
Clearly, $4\mathbb{Z} \smallsetminus (100\mathbb{Z} \smallsetminus 400\mathbb{Z})$ is the set of integers that is divisible by 4, excluding the ones that are divisible by 100, but including the ones that are divisible by 400.

We restrict the statement to $\mathbb{Z}^+ = \{1, 2, 3, \dots\}$ because in the Gregorian calendar there are no year $0$ and no negative years, as correctly remarked by @celtschk.
Anyway, from the mathematical point of view, the statement holds for every $y \in \mathbb{Z}$.

---

${}^*$
More in general, given the sets $A, B, C$, if $A \subseteq  B \subseteq C$, then $C \,\triangle\, B \,\triangle\, A = C \smallsetminus (B \smallsetminus A)$. The proof is straightforward and can be easily visualized using [Venn diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram).

Comment: "Note that $(4\mathbb{Z}) \,\Delta\, (100\mathbb{Z}) \,\Delta\, (400\mathbb{Z}) = 4\mathbb{Z} \smallsetminus (100\mathbb{Z} \smallsetminus 400\mathbb{Z})$" .... Is it?...  Why isn't it $(4\mathbb Z\setminus 100\mathbb Z)\setminus 400\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @fleablood - Note that $400 \in 4ℤ \smallsetminus (100ℤ \smallsetminus 400ℤ)$ but $400 \notin (4ℤ \smallsetminus 100ℤ) \smallsetminus 400ℤ$. Symmetric difference $\triangle $ is associative (see https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Symmetric_Difference_is_Associative), but difference $\smallsetminus$ is not.

Comment: Can I ask the reason for the downvote? What is wrong or unclear in my answer?